# MongoDb aggregate with limit and without limit

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

There is a collection in mongo
In the collection of 40 million records

```
db.getCollection('feedposts').aggregate([

   {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                {
                  "isOfficial": true
                },
                {
                  "creator": ObjectId("537f267c984539401ff448d2"),
                   type: { $nin: ['challenge_answer', 'challenge_win']}

                }
            ],
        }
  },
  {
      $sort: {timeline: -1}
  }
])
```

This request never ends

But if you add a limit before sorting, and the limit is higher than the total number of records in advance, for example, 1,000,000,000,000,000 - the request will be processed instantly

```
db.getCollection('feedposts').aggregate([

   {
        "$match": {
            "$or": [
                {
                  "isOfficial": true
                },
                {
                  "creator": ObjectId("537f267c984539401ff448d2"),
                   type: { $nin: ['challenge_answer', 'challenge_win']}

                }
            ],
        }
  },
   {
      $limit: 10000000000000000
  },

  {
      $sort: {timeline: -1}
  }
])
```

Please tell me why this is happening?
What problems can I expect in the future if I leave it this way?

Comment: That's not true. `$limit` takes a positive **integer** that specifies the maximum number of documents to pass along. So you cannot put `1,000,000,000,000,000`... Please show use real query

Comment: Please translate into `find` and provide the execution plan with `explain()`

Comment: you can use the explain on aggregation query to understand further. db.collname.explain().aggregate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: Mongo is using the wrong index for the query

***Why is this happening?***

Well basically every query you do Mongo simulates a quick "competition" between the relevant indexes in order to choose which one to use, the first index to retrieve 1001 documents "wins".

Now usually this situation of picking the wrong index occurs with ascending or descending fields and a matching index making this index with the fetching competition under certain conditions, Meaning this is very risky as you can have stable code that can suddenly become a huge bottleneck.

***What can we do?***

You have a few options:

1. Use the [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/aggregate/#hint-an-index) option and make Mongo use the compound index you have ready for this pipeline.
2. Drop the rogue index to ensure this will never happen again elsewhere (which is my recommended option).
3. Keep doing what you're doing. basically by adding this random `$limit` stage you're throwing Mongo's competition off and ensuring the right index will be picked.